# Input of 0 returns a NaN in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Nelson-Siegel is a method used to model interest rates. More info on Nelson-Siegel:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-income_attribution.

I have written a code like this:

```
function [ interest ] = Nelson_Siegel(s)
 beta0 = 0.0408; beta1 = -0.0396; beta2 = -0.0511; tau= 1.614;
 interest = beta0 + beta1*(tau/s)*(1-exp(-s/tau))+beta2*((tau/s)*(1-exp(-s/tau))-exp(-s/tau));
end
```

The problem is when I input a value of 0, it gives me a value of NaN. It should be equal to 0 instead. Not sure where it is going wrong.

Comment: you have `(tau/s)` in there.  what happens what `s=0`?

Comment: Are you sure you should be entering a value of `0`? It doesn't really make sense, these are interest rates so why would you ever want it at 0? Maybe be the shortest term you should be looking at is overnight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to your divide-by-zero problem could be to compare against [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html), and consider that as a special case:

```
function [ interest ] = Nelson_Siegel(s)
  beta0 = ...
  if abs(s)<eps,
    interest = 0;
  else
    interest = beta0 + beta1*(tau/s)*...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because of this term:

```
T = beta1*(tau/s)*(1-exp(-s/tau))
```

As `s ⇒ 0`, `τ/s ⇒ ∞`, and

```
1-exp(-s/τ) ⇒ 1-e⁰ = 1-1 = 0
```

Thus:

```
s ⇒ 0 ∴ T ⇒ β₁·∞·0 ⇒ NaN
```

since `∞·0` isn't a proper number.